# Sending knockout Data to Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an MVC form which i am populating and am able to send back and forth via form post. I have a knockout observableArray that is collecting the selected items on a list.

```
  <select multiple id="RecipientsListSelect" size="20" class="form-control" data-bind="options: recipientList, selectedOptions: selectedRecipientList, optionsText: function(i) {return i.FirstName +' '+ i.LastName}"></select>
```

What i am experiencing is that when I add data-bind= click:submit to my submit form post button i am only receiving the knockout data and not the rest of the data in my MVC view

```
 <button type="submit" @*data-bind="click: submit"*@ class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

Here is my Controller Post Method.

```
  [HttpPost,ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult eBlast(eBlastViewModel model)
        {


            List<string> eblastList = new List<string>();


            List<string> recipients = model.Recipients;

            var emailText = model.TextMail;
            var subject = model.EmailSubject;
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();


            eblastList.Add("");

            var eblastsubjecttext = InteBlast.GetSelectedEblastSubjectText(model.EblastSubject);

            emailUtility.SendEblastEmail("EBlast", emailText, eblastList, subject, true, "", "ff", msg);
            model.ListEblastSubject = InteBlast.GetEmailSubject();
            return View(model);



        }
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
  public class eBlastViewModel
    {

        public IEnumerable<EmailSubject> ListEblastSubject { get; set; }

        public int EblastSubject { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string EmailSubject { get; set; }

        public List<string> SendEmailToList { get; set; }

        public List<string> Recipients { get; set; }

        public int[] SelectedRecipients { get; set; }

        public string SendEmailTo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EmailContent> Contents { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Attachments { get; set; }

        public string TextMail { get; set; }


    }
```

My post Json method collects my observable and sends it to the controller .

```
 $.post("eBlast", request, function () {

            })
```

The problem is that if i get rid of sending the data to the post via knockout it sends the rest of the data in my view and not my observable. How do i make it send both?

Since i have a property of Recipients in my viewModel i attempted to pass the data like this

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Recipients, new {data_bind="value: eblastList"})
```

with no luck

Comment: Can you show your knockout Model as well as your HTML form ?

Comment: I can but really what i am trying to find out is why it sends one and not the other.

Comment: You're not showing enough information to reliably/easily reproduce the issue I think. (At any rate, do mind that there's [a `submit` binding handler too](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html).)